# Print a PDF with Electron

Tags: printing, electron

On my electron app, I have 2 buttons, one to download a PDF file and one to print it.

`win.webContents.print();` starts a printing job but prints the content of the window (i.e. my 2 buttons).

Is there a way to start a printing job with the content of my PDF without displaying this PDF in a new window?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you download the PDF, are you keeping it in memory?  If so you can just use fs (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to write the file to disk.

Comment: @dbaq any luck?

Comment: Nope. If you find something, lmk.

Comment: @AnkitSolanki If it is still actual, then I had the same problem but managed to solve it. I recently published an NPM package to print PDF files from Node.js and Electron. Works fine on Windows and Unix-like operating systems: https://github.com/artiebits/pdf-to-printer.